# Tic tac toe game predict a tie(draw)

Tags: java

I'm making a tic tac toe game for my homework and the teacher told me to print a tie when only a tie can come out. (under the assumption that the players are not smart) For example,

```
x o x
- - -
o x o
```

can only result in a tie so when this happens we are supposed to end the game with "this is a tie"

I have finished coding the tic tac toe with a char[][] array but I have no idea how to predict a draw.

```
public class Ttt22 {

    private static int spacesLe

    private static char[][] board;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // the first move belongs to X.
        System.out.println("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe");
        board = new char[3][3];
        initializeBoard();
        firstDraw();
        char mark = 'X';

        while (true) {
            int square = getLegalMove(mark);
            move(square, mark);
            draw();
            if (is3InRow(mark)) {
                System.out.println(mark + " wins!");
                break;
            }

            if (isBoardFull()) {
                System.out.println("Tie game!");
                break;
            }

            if (mark == 'X') {
                mark = 'O';
            }
            else {
                mark = 'X';
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getLegalMove (char mark) {
        java.util.Scanner console = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(mark + "'s next move: ");
            int square = console.nextInt();
            if ((square >= 1) &&
                (square <= 9) &&
                (isSquareEmpty(square))) {
                return square;
            }
            System.out.println("\nIllegal move, try again\n");
        }
    }

    public static void initializeBoard () {
        spacesLeft = 9;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    public static void firstDraw () {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println(" " + 1 + " | " + 2 + " | " + 3);
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println("---+---+---");
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println(" " + 4 + " | " + 5 + " | " + 6);
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println("---+---+---");
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println(" " + 7 + " | " + 8 + " | " + 9);
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void draw () {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println(" " + board[0][0] + " | "
                           + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2]);
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println("---+---+---");
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println(" " + board[1][0] + " | "
                           + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2]);
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println("---+---+---");
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println(" " + board[2][0] + " | "
                           + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2]);
        System.out.println("   |   |   ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void move (int square, char mark) {
        if (isSquareEmpty(square)) {
            spacesLeft = spacesLeft - 1;
        }
        int row = (square - 1) / 3;
        int column = (square - 1) % 3;
        board[row][column] = mark;
    }

    public static boolean isSquareEmpty (int square) {
        int row = (square - 1) / 3;
        int column = (square - 1) % 3;
        return (board[row][column] == ' ');
    }

    public static boolean is3InRow (char mark) {            
        return
            (board[0][0] == mark && board[0][1] == mark && board[0][2] == mark) ||
            (board[1][0] == mark && board[1][1] == mark && board[1][2] == mark) ||
            (board[2][0] == mark && board[2][1] == mark && board[2][2] == mark) ||
            (board[0][0] == mark && board[1][0] == mark && board[2][0] == mark) ||
            (board[0][1] == mark && board[1][1] == mark && board[2][1] == mark) ||
            (board[0][2] == mark && board[1][2] == mark && board[2][2] == mark) ||
            (board[0][0] == mark && board[1][1] == mark && board[2][2] == mark) ||
            (board[0][2] == mark && board[1][1] == mark && board[2][0] == mark);
    }

    public static boolean isBoardFull () {
        return spacesLeft == 0;
    }
}
```

the expected result is when the game is

```
x o x
- - -
o x o
```

It prints "Tie game!" and the game ends

Comment: You can run a BFS/DFS based search as suggested in NiVeR's answer, another alternative way is checking whether each of the nine letters still has probability of forming a three-char-line. Check each letter one by one, for example if top-left char assigned to a letter (if not skip to next letter), top left letter may form a group with letters in top row, left column or main diagonal. If all these groups contain a letter that is different than top-left letter, game ending line can not be formed from top-left letter. Only doing this for first 5 letters are enough (symmetry). Faster than search.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, simply, after every move of the *"players"*, launch an automatic process that will compute all outcomes of the game starting from that particular position. If all of those end in a draw, then you can safely declare that the final outcome is a draw. Of course, this is the first, not at all optimized solution, that comes to my mind immediately. If you are interested, you can probably work on some optimizations based on that.

Answer (score 0):

There are algorithms for this kind of task, I suggest you read about [Minimax](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-tic-tac-toe-game-unbeatable-by-using-the-minimax-algorithm-9d690bad4b37)